# how to encrypt 8 alphabet into 8 bit binary code?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

In my project I need to encrypt 8 alphabetical letters into 8 bit binary code and then decrypt 8 bit binary into that same 8 alphabet using some private key.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to show us your effort, before getting any help from us

Comment: Yes ... think about your challenge write some code ... get it working first ... show your work

Comment: Firstly, I convert each letter into their corresponding ASCII binary code and I tried to simplify each 8 bit ASCII into single digit but I don't have any Idea for simplification that's why I am asking.

Comment: Have a look at [RC4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4).  It is obsolescent and not completely secure, but it is simple to program and easy to code.